# Odd result in python scipy FFT

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I have access scipy and want to create a FFT about simple Gaussian function which is **exp(-t^2)**. And also it's well known that fourier transform of **exp(−t^2)** is **√πexp(−π^2*k^2)**. But FFT of **exp(-t^2)** was not same as **√πexp(−π^2*k^2)**.

I have tried the following code:

```
import scipy.fftpack as fft
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#FFT
N=int(1e+3)
T=0.01 #sample period
t = np.linspace(0,N*T, N)

h=np.exp(-t**2)
H_shift=2*np.abs(fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(h)/N))
freq=fft.fftshift(fft.fftfreq(h.shape[0],t[1]-t[0]))


#Comparing FFT with fourier transform
def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x**2)
def F(k):
    return (np.pi**0.5)*np.exp((-np.pi**2)*(k**2))

plt.figure(num=1)
plt.plot(freq,F(freq),label=("Fourier Transform"))
plt.legend()
plt.figure(num=2)
plt.plot(freq,H_shift,label=("FFT"))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
#Checking Parseval's Theorm
S_h=integrate.simps(h**2,t)
#0.62665690150683084
S_H_s=integrate.simps(H_shift**2,freq)
#0.025215875346935791
S_F=integrate.simps(F(freq)**2,freq)
#1.2533141373154999
```

The graph I plotted is not same, also values of FFT do not follow Parseval's theorm. [image]. It has to be **S_H_s=S_h*2**, but my result was not. I think that **S_H_s** which is result of FFT is wrong value Because of **S_F=S_h*2**.

Is there any problem in my code?? Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you plot your input signal `h` and verify that it looks like a Gaussian.

Spoiler alert: it doesn't, it is half a Gaussian!

By cutting it like this, you introduce a lot of high frequencies that you see in your plot.

To do this experiment correctly, follow this recipe to create your input signal:

```
t = np.linspace(-(N/2)*T,(N/2-1)*T, N)
h = np.exp(-t**2)
h = fft.ifftshift(h)
```

The `ifftshift` function serves to move the `t=0` location to the leftmost array element. Note that `t` here is constructed carefully such that `t=0` is exactly in the right place for this to work correctly, assuming an even-sized `N`. You can verify that `fft.ifftshift(t)[0]` is 0.0.